# Render to string with context?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-context

I have a component (EmailBuilder) which uses the react context api to render some things, I'd like to render that to html, I tried this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { EmailBuilder } from './EmailBuilder';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

export const EmailBuilderPage = (props: any) => {
    const element = <EmailBuilder />
    return <>
        {element}

        <br />
        <h1>HTML</h1>
        {ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)}
    </>
}
```

While that rendered the root of the element it failed to render any of the changes to the element from the context api.

Is that at all possible to do?